# Assembly Binding - using the wrong version of Unity, but why?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

Within this Selenium test project, I have a direct reference to Unity 3.0.0.0.

I have references to other DLLs that reference 2.505.0.2 of Unity.

I have this in my app.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.1.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I expected it to use V3 of Unity, but it keeps trying to use the old one.  The binding log is:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = INT\UKTHJHAR
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Audatex/Retail/Development/Server/AudaRetailAdministration.AutomatedUITests/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : AudaRetailAdministration.AutomatedUITests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Audatex\Retail\Development\Server\AudaRetailAdministration.AutomatedUITests\bin\Debug\AudaRetailAdministration.AutomatedUITests.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Audatex/Retail/Development/Server/AudaRetailAdministration.AutomatedUITests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think assembly bindings are working only for direct references.

Probably for preventing the use of different versions of the same assembly in a single application (or application domain maybe?)

If you use a component compiled with an other assembly version of the one wich is referenced by the application, the loading of this component will fail.

If you decompile the assembly wich references the older version of Unity, you will see that the Unity version is somehow hardcoded in the assembly metadatas.

Same problem in this post
[Why is assembly binding redirect not working in my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543132/why-is-assembly-binding-redirect-not-working-in-my-web-site)

I did resolve the problem by using the same assembly version in the application and its components. It may not be possible for you.

This problem is a drawback of complex applications published using the GAC. Now, people tend to use nugget packages to easily manage components dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this.  I am not entirely convinced by your answer though, as I have worked on projects where we have done exactly this, and redirect assemblies that are not directly referenced.

Comment: In the other projects, were the assemblies strongly-named too? I did get this error with several projects with this specific configuration.